# How can I remove an automatically placed LaTeX citation?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, bibtex, bibliography

My problem is following: I am citing 19 papers in the bibliography section of my LaTeX file, but whenever I run it in Texstudio to get a PDF, an additional citation appears: "Automatically placing footnotes...".
I had some footnotes which did not show up anywhere, so I assumed it could be to do with that. I deleted the footnotes and re-ran the PDFmaker about 5 times (because bibliographies are weird in LaTeX and apparently you need to run them 5 times before everything gets updated), but no effect: still that line is there.

Any ideas?

The code I am using to generate my bibliography:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{30}

    \bibitem{einstein} 
    A. Einstein: 
    \textit{Relativitätsprinzip und die aus demselben gezogenen Folgerungen}. 
    Jahrbuch der Radioaktivität, 4, 411–462 (1907)
    %all other citations
\end{thebibliography}
```

Thanks!!
[what I get after compilation, citation number 20 should not be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKtbp.png)

[I am using the rev-tex template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QkRA.png)

Comment: please add a compilable [mre] to your code (as text and not as image)

Comment: Maybe try the `nofootinbib` option,  but without any code to test, that's just a guess

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks very much! Two things helped:
1. my appendix section was in front of the bibliography - corrected that
2. put in the nofootinbib as you said.